# I think I am not getting values from struct variable in if statment

Tags: c

I am a beginner in `C` programming and I was making a library management system. The detail is the library will have the capacity of only 100 book and I wanted that If the user enter the quantity greater than capacity the the program re-ask the user to input in given limit but when I run the program I am not getting the output as expected, I am a bit week in English so please forgive me for any mistakes in question.

The problem is happening in the `if condition block` in `switch case` , `case 1.`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct book
{
    char name[50];
    char Authorname[20];
    int Quantity;
} bk;

static int bookno = 1;

void incrementBN()
{
    bookno++;
}
void decrementBN()
{
    bookno--;
}

int main()
{
    int capacity = 100;
    bk book[capacity];
    int TotalQuantity = 0;

    int option;

    // system("cls");
    puts("Welcome to Library Managemt");
    puts("---------------------------");
    puts("1. Add Books.");
    puts("2. View Books.");
    puts("3. Remove Books.");
    puts("4. Issue Books.");
    puts("5. View Issue Books.");
    puts("6. Return Books.");
    puts("---------------------------");
    printf("Enter your option : ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    getchar();

    switch (option)
    {
    case 1:

        if (TotalQuantity < capacity)
        {

            char *YN = (char *)malloc(1 * sizeof(char));
            *YN = 'y';

            while (*YN == 'y' || *YN == 'Y')
            {
                printf("Enter Details for Book No %d.\n", bookno);
                printf("Enter Name of book No : ");
                gets(book[bookno].name);
                printf("\nName of book : %s \n", book[bookno].name);

                printf("Enter Name of Author : ");
                gets(book[bookno].Authorname);
                printf("Name of Author : %s \n", book[bookno].Authorname);

                printf("Enter Quantity of books : ");
                scanf("%d", &book[bookno].Quantity);
                getchar();
                printf("Quantity Available : %d and totial quantiuty is %d\n", book[bookno].Quantity, (book[bookno].Quantity + TotalQuantity));

                incrementBN();
                // issue here the compiler is not going into this if code if user enter quatity               greater than capacity
                if (capacity < (book[bookno].Quantity) + TotalQuantity)
                {
                    printf("Enter Quantity of books less than %d : ", capacity - TotalQuantity);
                    scanf("%d", &book[bookno].Quantity);
                }
                else
                {
                    TotalQuantity += book[bookno].Quantity;
                }
                printf("Do you want to add new book : (Y/N) ");
                scanf("%c", &(*YN));
                getchar();
            }

            free(YN);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You Cannot Add new Books because Space is full.\n");
        }
        break;

    case 2:

    {
        int *index = (int *)calloc(1, sizeof(int));
        *index += 1;
        while (*index < bookno)
        {
            printf("\nName of book : %s \n", book[*index].name);
            printf("Name of Author : %s \n", book[*index].Authorname);
            printf("Quantity Available : %d \n", book[*index].Quantity);
        }
    }
    break;

    default:
        printf("Please Select the Valid option\n");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was just trying to practice the things I have learned but here I am getting the issue but I am not getting the issue, the compiler is printing the values of quantity user entered but not executing these values in if block can anyone help me and tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Side note: there's a few thing that are weird about this code. 1) why `char *YN = (char *)malloc(1 * sizeof(char))` instead of just `char YN`?. 2) `&(*YN)` is the same as just `YN`, 3) `bookno` doesn't need to be a global variable. You can just make it a local variable in `main`, and drop the increment / decrement functions

Comment: You `incrementBN()` at the wrong time.

Comment: oih Thank you so much I got it when the increment happen the value then will save in the next struct array of book thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your program and noted both the compiler warnings I received along with the behavior of the program, following is a refactored version of your program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>          /* Added so that the "toupper" function could be used to simplify Y/N character testing         */

typedef struct book
{
    char name[50];
    char Authorname[20];
    int Quantity;
} bk;

int main()
{
    int capacity = 100;
    bk book[capacity];
    int TotalQuantity = 0;
    int bookno = -1;        /* Array indices start at "0" - the initial increment of "bookno" will set this value to "0"    */
    char YN;                /* Simpler to declare the character than defining a pointer and then allocating space           */

    char work_name[50];
    char work_author[20];
    int  work_quantity;

    int option;

    while(1)                /* Enclose the process inside of a "while" loop - exits when user selects new option "7"        */
    {
        // system("cls");
        puts("Welcome to Library Managememt");
        puts("---------------------------");
        puts("1. Add Books.");
        puts("2. View Books.");
        puts("3. Remove Books.");
        puts("4. Issue Books.");
        puts("5. View Issue Books.");
        puts("6. Return Books.");
        puts("7. Exit.");                       /* Provide a simple option to end the program   */
        puts("---------------------------");
        printf("Enter your option : ");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:

            if (TotalQuantity < capacity)
            {
                YN = 'Y';

                while (toupper(YN) == 'Y')
                {
                    bookno++;                                           /* Increment the index counter here         */
                    printf("Enter details for book no %d.\n", bookno + 1);
                    printf("Enter name of book no %d: ", bookno + 1);
                    getchar();
                    fgets(work_name, 49, stdin);                        /* Use fgets in lieu of gets                                    */
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)                        /* Remove any leftover newline character from the data entry    */
                    {
                        if (work_name[i] == '\n')
                        {
                            work_name[i] = '\0';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    printf("Name of book : %s \n", work_name);

                    printf("Enter name of author : ");
                    fgets(work_author, 19, stdin);                      /* Use fgets in lieu of gets                                    */
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)                        /* Remove any leftover newline character from the data entry    */
                    {
                        if (work_author[i] == '\n')
                        {
                            work_author[i] = '\0';
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    printf("Name of author : %s \n", work_author);

                    printf("Enter quantity of books : ");
                    scanf("%d", &work_quantity);
                    printf("Quantity available : %d and total quantiuty is: %d\n", work_quantity, (work_quantity + TotalQuantity));

                    // Issue here the compiler is not going into this if code if user enter quantity greater than capacity
                    while (capacity < (work_quantity + TotalQuantity))
                    {
                        printf("Enter quantity of books less than %d : ", capacity - TotalQuantity + 1);
                        scanf("%d", &work_quantity);
                    }

                    // Once an allowable quantity is entered, add the book information to the structure array.

                    TotalQuantity += work_quantity;

                    strcpy(book[bookno].name, work_name);
                    strcpy(book[bookno].Authorname, work_author);
                    book[bookno].Quantity = work_quantity;

                    if (TotalQuantity >= capacity)      /* Need to exit the while loop prompting for more books if capacity is reached */
                        break;

                    printf("Do you want to add new book : (Y/N) ");
                    scanf(" %c", &YN);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You cannot add new books because space is full!\n");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
        {
            printf("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -\n");
            for (int i = 0; i <= bookno; i++)                   /* This sort of listing function is done with a "for" loop */
            {
                printf("Name of book. . . .: %s \n", book[i].name);
                printf("Name of Author. . .: %s \n", book[i].Authorname);
                printf("Quantity Available.: %d \n", book[i].Quantity);
            }
        }
        break;

        case 3:
            break;      /* TBD */

        case 4:
            break;      /* TBD */

        case 5:
            break;      /* TBD */

        case 6:
            break;      /* TBD */

        case 7:
            return 0;   /* Go ahead and exit this program */

        default:
            printf("Please Select the Valid option\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wish the parts that needed some refactored code could have been localized to one section of the program, but due to the behavior I ran into, I decided to include the complete refactored code.  Following are some key points.

- As noted in the good comments, it is simpler to just define a character and utilize it rather than define a pointer for a character, allocate memory for the character, user pointer references, and then finally freeing up the character memory.  So "*YN" is just defined as "char YN".
- The character include file "<ctype.h>" was added to allow for the usage of uppercase manipulation, making the "Yes/No" testing simpler.
- Noting that the program is using an array of book structures, revision of the array manipulation was performed to accommodate the fact that arrays start at index "0".
- Noting that when the program was compiled, the compiler gave warnings of the usage of the "gets" function.  This function really should not be used anymore and the "fgets" function should be utilized in its place.
- Just as a convention for data entry, book information was entered into work variables, and once all verification had been passed, the work information would be stored into the appropriate book structure element.

With that, following is a quick test at the terminal entering in information for a couple of books.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Library/bin/Release$ ./Library 
Welcome to Library Managememt
---------------------------
1. Add Books.
2. View Books.
3. Remove Books.
4. Issue Books.
5. View Issue Books.
6. Return Books.
7. Exit.
---------------------------
Enter your option : 1
Enter details for book no 1.
Enter name of book no 1: Book #1
Name of book : Book #1 
Enter name of author : Author #1
Name of author : Author #1 
Enter quantity of books : 66
Quantity available : 66 and total quantiuty is: 66
Do you want to add new book : (Y/N) Y
Enter details for book no 2.
Enter name of book no 2: Book #2
Name of book : Book #2 
Enter name of author : Author #2
Name of author : Author #2 
Enter quantity of books : 34
Quantity available : 34 and total quantiuty is: 100
Welcome to Library Managememt
---------------------------
1. Add Books.
2. View Books.
3. Remove Books.
4. Issue Books.
5. View Issue Books.
6. Return Books.
7. Exit.
---------------------------
Enter your option : 1
You cannot add new books because space is full!
Welcome to Library Managememt
---------------------------
1. Add Books.
2. View Books.
3. Remove Books.
4. Issue Books.
5. View Issue Books.
6. Return Books.
7. Exit.
---------------------------
Enter your option : 7
```

Also, I included additional comments within the refactored code to try to explain and clarify the reasoning for these suggested coding techniques.  As you learn the language, you will find that there are a multitude of ways to achieve the desired functionality.  This is just one suggested way.  As always, search out tutorial literature that is available to assist in your learning of the language.

Comment: Oh, Your guidance is so good , I understand everything you have told . Next time I will try to write code in proper ways and will try to use appropriate data types for data.